# transform dataframe to array / list

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

I have a dataframe from this function

```
def get_box_plot_data(labels, bp):
    rows_list = []

    for i in range(len(labels)):
        dict1 = {}
        dict1[''] = labels[i]
        dict1['Minimum'] = np.min(bp['fliers'][i].get_ydata())
        dict1[f'{my_whis[0]}%'] = bp['whiskers'][i*2].get_ydata()[1]
        dict1['Q1: 25%'] = bp['boxes'][i].get_ydata()[1]
        dict1['Median'] = bp['medians'][i].get_ydata()[1]
        dict1['Mean'] = f'{mean:.3f}'
        dict1['Q3: 75%'] = bp['boxes'][i].get_ydata()[2]
        dict1[f'{my_whis[1]}%'] = bp['whiskers'][(i*2)+1].get_ydata()[1]
        dict1['Maximum'] = np.max(bp['fliers'][i].get_ydata())
        rows_list.append(dict1)

    return pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
```

And woul like to transform it to an array or list to plot it next/under to my boxplot.

What I get is this

```
          Minimum     1%  Q1: 25%  Median   Mean  Q3: 75%    99%  Maximum
0  X    4.924  4.977    4.988   4.993  4.992    4.997  5.007    5.017
['', 'Minimum', '1%', 'Q1: 25%', 'Median', 'Mean', 'Q3: 75%', '99%', 'Maximum']
[['X' 4.924 4.977 4.988 4.993 '4.992' 4.997 5.007 5.017]]
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide what are feeding to function
Never the less you can get an array by choosing which column, np.array(df['column'])

Comment: Alex, can you also put what exactly are you trying to print where you have: What I get is this.